# Recursion to pull multiple substrings from an image file

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I'm working with a database that for each entry has a list of parameters formatted in a uniform fashion (in a text file), but than jammed into a single field as an image.

I need query to extract multiple substrings from this image. The criteria is this:
If I'm pulling information for machine 8, I want every string that starts with
'[08', and I want every other character until the carriage return.
This code successfully extracts everything, but I don't know how to use a where clause on modified data.

```
DECLARE @POS INT
SET @POS = 0
DECLARE @PSU VARCHAR(12)
SET @PSU ='PSU-1.4'

WHILE (@POS < 1000) BEGIN
    SELECT SUBSTRING( CONVERT( VARCHAR( MAX)
                             , CONVERT( BINARY(8000)
                                      , BITS
                                      )
                             )
                    , @POS --SUBSTRING START
                    , CHARINDEX( CHAR(13)
                               , CONVERT( VARCHAR(MAX)
                                        , CONVERT( BINARY(8000)
                                                 , BITS
                                                 )
                                        )
                               , @POS --CHARINDEX OFFSET
                               ) - @POS --SHOULD BE THE SAME AS THE SUBSTRING
                    )
        AS [PARAMETER]
      FROM PART_BINARY
     WHERE PART_ID = @PSU --AND PARAMETER LIKE '[08%'
    SET @POS = 2 + (SELECT @POS + CHARINDEX( CHAR(13)
                                           , CONVERT( VARCHAR(MAX)
                                                    , CONVERT( BINARY(8000)
                                                             , BITS
                                                             )
                                                    )
                                           , @POS
                                           ) - @POS
                      FROM PART_BINARY
                     WHERE PART_ID = @PSU
                   )
END
GO
```

Below is a sample of some of converted text in the field that I would be parsing.

```
[41 Platen Seal Temp Nominal]           {275}   °F
[41 Platen Seal Temp High Limit]        {284}   °F
[41 Platen Seal Temp Low Limit]         {270}   °F
[41 Aux Seal Temp Nominal]              {275}   °F
[41 Aux Seal Temp High Limit]           {284}   °F
[41 Aux Seal Temp Low Limit]            {270}   °F
[41 Platen Base Heat]                   {1}     On
[41 Dwell Main Nominal]                 {1.1}   sec
[41 Dwell Main High Limit]              {1.3}   sec
[41 Dwell Main Low Limit]               {0.9}   sec
[41 Dwell Aux Nominal]                  {1.1}   sec
[41 Dwell Aux High Limit]               {1.3}   sec
[41 Dwell Aux Low Limit]                {0.9}   sec
[41 Pressure Main Nominal]              {}      
[41 Pressure Main High Limit]           {}      
[41 Pressure Main Low Limit]            {}      
[41 Pressure Aux Nominal]               {}      
[41 Pressure Aux High Limit]            {}      
[41 Pressure Aux Low Limit]             {}      
#41 Teflon (top/bottom):                NONE / COARSE
#41 Rubber:                             2x 1/8" 65D

[76 Platen Seal Temp Nominal]           {285}   °F
[76 Platen Seal Temp High Limit]        {300}   °F
[76 Platen Seal Temp Low Limit]         {280}   °F
[76 Platen Base Heat]                   {1}     On
[76 Dwell Main Nominal]                 {0.67}  sec
[76 Dwell Main High Limit]              {0.84}  sec
[76 Dwell Main Low Limit]               {0.56}  sec
[76 Pressure Main Nominal]              {}      
[76 Pressure Main High Limit]           {}      
[76 Pressure Main Low Limit]            {}      
#76 Teflon (top/bottom):                NONE / COARSE
#76 Rubber:                             2x 1/8" 65D
```

Comment: please post an example of the text you want to parse.

Comment: This is an example of two different machines from a particular field.